# Can't run project in Android studio: ZipException: duplicate entry

Tags: android, android-intent

I have completed project..clean and Rebuild works fine in Android studio but when am going to run it shows below error message:

> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/squareup/picasso/Action$RequestWeakReference.class exception..

I tried this:

> configurations { all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4' }

but not solved. how to solve this issue?

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
 }
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

 repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
 }

 android {
 compileSdkVersion 22
 buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "myid"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
 }

 buildTypes {
     release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
 }

  compileOptions {
     sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
     targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
  }
 }

  dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
 compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
 compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.0.jar')
 compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.4.0@aar') {
     transitive = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the picasso library twice, remove either `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` or `compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')` and it should work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: it will be the same for your universal-image-loader, just keep compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) and remove the lines that improt picasso and universal-image-loader explicitly

Comment: same only...first time am removed compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar') then check ..second time am add that previous line and remove  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) thats also not work

Comment: You need to remove both compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar') and compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.0.jar')

Comment: am removed compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])  instead of compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar') and compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.0.jar')..its works now.. thanks for your help